# How to append the textview to the end of another textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am creating a Gallery application. Each image will show the title along with the name of the person who uploaded the image. Example of what I want is below:

[image]

Here the **Night is dark, but this darkness has the silence** is the title for the image, and the **shaggy boy** is the user who uploaded the image for example.

So, now I want **Night is dark, but this darkness has the silence** to be in the separate `textview` and the **shaggy boy** at the end of the **Night is dark, but this darkness has the silence**'s `textview` even if **Night is dark, but this darkness has the silence** is a single line or multi-line.

I have used the `Flexbox Layout` but I am failed to achieve what I want.

How to append the `textview` to the end of another `textview`?

Comment: just change textcolor in xml for the textviews and i guess it will serve the purpose.

Comment: But how to append another textview to the end of the first one?

Comment: You can look at `SpannableStringBuilder` which allows different styling for text in the same text view

Comment: if you are getting it done through java, you can do it with in same textview.

Comment: @ManzoorAhmad Don't you think it will be extra overhead in case of RecyclerView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single `TextView` and set its text String with a [`Spannable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable) and match each portion of text with indices here I am separating both portions by a hyphen; but you can change that as you would like.

```
TextView textView = findViewById(...);

String tag = "Night is dark, but this darkness has the silence - shaggy boy";
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(tag);

spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, tag.indexOf("-"), 0);
spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), tag.indexOf("-"), tag.length(), 0);
textView.setText(spannableString);
```

Comment: Don't you think its extra overhead in the case of RecylerView? Is there any other approach?

Comment: @StackOverflow I guess if you used a couple of TextViews that would be overhead of calculating view sizing and placement.. but let me double think if there is more efficient way

Comment: @StackOverflow please check the other answer.. decided to put it separately as it is different approach ... maybe that would be more compact and better in performance .. but not completely sure

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just get the text of the author's TextView and add it to the String of the first TextView?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `TextView` with String palceholders of the quote and the author, and add the colors using HTML tags.

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>

    <string name="tag">
        <![CDATA[
            <font color="#00000">%1$s</font> -
            <font color="#D3D3D3">%2$s</font>
        ]]>
    </string>


</resources>
```

**Behavior:**

```
String message = "Night is dark, but this darkness has the silence";
String name = "shaggy boy";

String formattedTag = String.format(getString(R.string.tag), message, name);

textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(formattedTag));
```